# Parse url with regexp, pattern doesnt match optional string

Tags: javascript, regex

I've got these strings I want to parse:

```
?forum=Jiné akce a jiné#comments
?trening=140#$|Pralinka
?novinka=87#comments
?forum=Mimo mísu#comments
?forum=Členské forum#comments
?trening=139#comments
```

and I want to output array like

```
 1. forum 
 2. Jiné akce a jiné
 3. comments
```

or

```
 1. trening
 2. 140
 3. Pralinka
```

So I wrote following regexp:

```
\?([a-z]{4,})\=(.+)\#(\$\|)?([a-z]+)
```

[Regex101](http://regex101.com/r/aX7lO6)

But It's not working in second case (optional string part).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that by default, regex are case sensitive... So `[a-z]` can't match `Pralinka`. You can fix that by using the `i` (case insensitive) flag, or with:

```
\?([a-z]{4,})=(.+)#(?:\$\|)?([A-Za-z]+)
```

Notice that there is no need to escape the `=` or the `#` (we're not in free spacing mode), and I added a non capturing group `(?:...)` so that `Pralinka` will be in the same capturing group as `comment`.

The demo is [here](http://regex101.com/r/pN9oS5)

Comment: Good, I didn't know about non-capturing groups. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`[a-z]+` does not match `Pralinka` because `P` is an uppercase letter.

[Fixed regex](http://regex101.com/r/gG0fB8)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a global flag: `/g`.

http://regex101.com/r/vR0oM4

Comment: See the second line, its not parsing it - thats the problem.